# Is it possible to write to an open pipe (from a C program) from the command line?

Tags: c

Say I have a C program which creates a child throught `fork`. The parent processus ends before the child ends, and the child is blocked on a `read` system call because of an empty pipe.

If the processus ID of the child is `1500`, and by using the shell command  `ls -l /proc/1500/fd`
I see that a pipe is open, is it possible to write to this pipe from the terminal using a shell command so that the `read` system call unblocks and the child process finish its execution?

Comment: Have you tried it? Seems fairly straightforward to test: `echo "foo" >> /proc/1500/fd/FDGOESHERE`.

Comment: If you've handled it properly — closed enough file descriptors — the child should unblock when the parent dies as it gets EOF on the pipe.  Maybe you didn't close the write end of the pipe in the child process?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No kidding. I have him answer to question he asked and question I think he should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there done that.

Sh answer:

```
cat whatever >> /proc/pid/fd/0
```

C answer:

```
pid_t pid = whatever;
char buf[30];
sprintf(buf, "/proc/%d/fd/0", pid);
FILE *f = fopen(buf, "w");
```

But you appear to have the problem of have left the writing half of the pipe open in the child process. You should close it (see `man 2 close`) it immediately after your `fork()` call that way the reader doesn't get stuck but can observe the end of pipe. The launcher should normally look something like this.

```
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pipe(pipefd);

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        /* ... */
        /* usually this goes to exec but it doesn't have to */
        _exit(3);
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    if (pid < 0) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        return ;
    }
    int pipefeed = pipefd[0];
    /* ... */
    /* I'm guessing in your case you don't wait() */
```

Comment: You weren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close _both_ of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Of course, if you're using the `exec*` family on Linux (and some BSDs, but it's not standardized to my knowledge), you could avoid the trouble in the first place by making sure to open all the file descriptors with `O_CLOEXEC` so they get closed automatically when you `exec*`. Or if something else opened it for you, use `fcntl` to set `FD_CLOEXEC` after the fact (though that usage is subject to race conditions if you're not careful). `dup3` (or `fcntl` with `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`) would let you do duplicating with the flag set from the moment of duplication as well.

Comment: Can you mark the file descriptors from `pipe()` with `FD_CLOEXEC` in the pipe creation operation, @ShadowRanger?  Yes, using `FD_CLOEXEC` and related options is frequently good — but I don't think it is universally available (even on Linux or BSD).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As with the others, Linux (kernel 2.6.27, glibc 2.9 support) offers `pipe2` as an equivalent for `pipe` that accepts an extra `flags` argument, which can include `O_CLOEXEC`. But again, not a POSIX feature, so portability is limited. It looks like `fcntl`+`F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` is specified in POSIX.1-2008, so you could do a portable dup with raceless `CLOEXEC` via `fcntl`. Only setting `FD_CLOEXEC` (risking races) is standardized as far back as POSIX.1-2001.